# How to retrieve single value from array in codeigniter's controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller code to insert record.

```
function insert()
{
    $first_name=$this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name=$this->input->post('last_name');
    $father_name=$this->input->post('father_name');
    $doj=$this->input->post('doj');
    $course=$this->input->post('course_name');
    $fee_pay=$this->input->post('fee_pay');
    $photo=$this->input->post('photo');


    $input=array(
    'first_name'=>$first_name,
    'last_name'=>$last_name,
    'father_name'=>$father_name,
    'date_of_join'=>$doj,
    'course'=>$course
    );

    if($first_name!="" && $last_name!="" && $father_name!="" && $doj!="" && $course!="")
    {
        if(!$this->payment_model->insert($input))
        {
            //this is code to get data from fee database.
            $fee['t']=$this->payment_model->select_fee($course);
            //this code to get data from regestration database.         
            $id_data['data']=array($this->payment_model->select_id($first_name, $last_name, $father_name, $doj, $course));

            echo "Student Detail Inserted";



            $this->load->view('payment_step2');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "there is some problem in insertion";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please enter all the option to insert detail of student";
    }

}
```

Comment: in this code i have two array which i need. but i need only one value from $fee['t] array, & same from $id_data['data'] array.
now when i try to retrive data from these array using foreach loop in controller, then i didn't get value. but value's are present in array, because on use of print_r($fee); i get all value.
help me out tell me how i retrive value from array in variable in controller.

regards
vikas siwach

Comment: edit the question and __explain__ what you want. what is expected output.

Comment: from what you show so far, you claim that $fee array should contains all the values you need, you simply can't get it out. I would then guess the problem might be in your foreach loop instead of the code you post above?
Maybe showing your foreach loop's code & result of it might be a good idea?

Comment: Post your model too and show the `var_dump` of your array what you are getting and the structure you need.